# If Condition is not working for screen width

Tags: javascript, php

I got screen width by using javascript:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">var sw = document.body.scrollWidth ;</script>
```

Then i stored the value of the width in a php variable :-

```
$screenWidth1 = "<script>document.writeln(sw);</script>";
```

Now i want to use `$screenWidth1` in a condition like this:-

```
if ($screenWidth1 < '960') {echo "working";}
```

But it does not work, when we print `$screenWidth1`, it shows the correct value, but in condition its not work.

Please let me know if there any solution.

Comment: You can't set PHP variables from Javascript. PHP runs when the page is being sent to the client, Javascript runs after it's done.

Comment: `document.write` happens on the client, not the server.